# Avoid Line Breaks with HTML programming

Tags: html

How do I avoid line breaks in my code? For example:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com"><strong>Yay!</strong>
```

I don't want to separate the link with a line break between the Yay comment> How do I do that?

Comment: Your question is unclear, please add more details by using the `edit` button below your question. Where is the comment you talk about? What is your _current_ html markup? Please post it. Better even make a fiddler (jsfiddle.net). Thanks.

Comment: css property white-space: nowrap; :)

Answer (score 1):

Give the link a style of display:inline to keep the element inline with the rest of the text around it. If you're trying to keep the link itself from wrapping use white-space:nowrap.

Comment: That won't change the line wrapping _inside_ an anchor.

Comment: Was that the question? I thought he just wanted an inline link. I edited my answer to cover both cases.

Comment: No one knows what the OPs question actually is, since the question is vague. That is why I asked in a comment. I prefer to know the question before answering it :-)

Answer (score 0):

try with giving CSS Property to avoid line breaks of text

```
white-space: nowrap;
```